# putting html content between php function

Tags: php, html, function

i need to put some html content in  a variable for generating pdf using mpdf, is there any way to assign html content to a variable in a php function.

this is what i am trying.

```
     function getInvoice($conn,$uid,$id,$invoice_no)
        {



       echo "something";


        ob_start();
        ?>
    $content='<html>

    <body style="padding-top: 0px">
    <page>
    my html content                 
    </page><body><?php echo "something"?;></body><html>'



    <?php


    $content .= ob_get_clean();
  }

    ?>
```

What i need is that the all the content in html get assign to $content variable.
It is not working because it is between php execution function.

Comment: Remove all PHP start and end tag before and after $content variable. Inside variable remove PHP tags and use concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
function getInvoice($conn,$uid,$id,$invoice_no)
{    
     echo $something = "something";

     ob_start();

     $content='<html>    
     <body style="padding-top: 0px">
     <page>
     my html content                 
     </page><body>'.$something.'</body><html>';    

     $content .= ob_get_clean();
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the output buffer will only collect data sent to stdout after `ob_start` and before `ob_get_clean`.  *Your code was broken as it looks like you are trying to set the php variable `$contents` in html, then collecting that*.

The result when you ran `$contents .= ob_get_clean();` was being set to this value - which you were then passing as `html` to mPDF to make a pdf file from.  The following is not valid html.

```
$content='<html>
<body style="padding-top: 0px">
<page>
my html content                 
</page><body>something</body><html>'
```

Additionally, the use of `.-` is to add two strings together. Since you want the `$content` to contain valid html, this was mucking things up.

The fix below ensures that the (*valid html*) content is collected into `$content` as it appears is your intent.

```
function getInvoice($conn,$uid,$id,$invoice_no) {
    ob_start();
$content='<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//classes.gymate.co.in/assets/bower_components/uikit/css/uikit.almost-flat.min.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/main.min.css" media="all">
<style>body{font-family:\'roboto\'; .md-card {box-shadow: none; } .uk-width-small-3-5 {width: 40%;}</style>
</head>
<body style="padding-top: 0px">
<page>
my html content                 
</page><body>' . "something" . '</body><html>';

    echo $content;

    $content = ob_get_clean();

    include("../plugins/mpdf/mpdf.php");
    $mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4','','',10,10,5,5,5,5);
    $mpdf->SetFont('roboto');
    $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('<p style="padding-top: 18px; font-size: 12px;"></p><p style="text-align:right; font-size: 12px;">Page {PAGENO} of {nbpg}</p></p>');
    //$stylesheet = file_get_contents('../assets/css/main.min.css');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
    $mpdf->writeHTML($content);
    $mpdf->Output("pdf-save-data/reciept.pdf","F");

    echo "PDF File Created";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
function getInvoice($conn,$uid,$id,$invoice_no) {
    echo $something = "something";
    ob_start(); 
    $content='<html><body style="padding-top: 0px"><page>my html content</page><body>'.$something.'</body><html>';
    $content .= ob_get_clean();
}
?>
```

Just make sure you have your single and double quotes closed correctly.

Note: Also i personally prefer not to give line breaks in the html when you are going to assgin it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<<<html` and `html` to achieve this. Example is below

[image]

Comment: Actually i tried. But i could not format as i want to do. So just pasted the image for understanding.

Comment: You tried to post code and you couldn't format it? No one else has problems formatting code here.

Comment: When i press enter after <<<HTML, the formate is collapsed.. If you can then give a try.