# How can I send looped data via json?

Tags: php, json, ajax, loops, foreach

I send data via json. It is working well:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "json.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        encode: true,
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            $(".blue").html(data.blue);
            $(".red").html(data.red);
        }
    });
```

json.php

```
$array['blue'] = "blue array";
$array['red'] = "red content";
echo json_encode($array);
```

My problem is now, that instead of..

```
blue array
```

...I want to send:

```
$pdo = $db->query('SELECT * FROM data;');
while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo  "<li>".$row['name']."</li>";
}
```

is this possible?

Comment: Don't use echo. Instead of that, directly assign those html tags as a string to `$array['blue']`. Something like `$array['blue'].="<li>".$row['name']."</li>";`

Comment: @siddiq Thank you, I updated my question to show that my content is more complex. What can I do in this case?

Comment: No matter how big your string is. Still the entire output 'll be considered as a string. Just assign it to the variable as per my previous comment. check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41478701/putting-html-content-between-php-function/41479160#41479160) this to assign a big html content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an extremely basic example:

```
<?php
$json = array(
    'blue' => '',
    'red' => 'Empty red content or whatever'
);

$pdo = $db->query('SELECT * FROM data;');
while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $json['blue'].= "<li>".$row['name']."</li>";
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Not sure what logic you would use to actually populate `red` but you can work it into the while loop or whatever.

Comment: Thank you, I will check this out and let you know if it worked

Comment: red should not be in the loop!

Comment: @Jarla It was just a guess. You can modify the code however you would like. See my update.